# VS 2017 & Nuget: How to find Analyzer packages with specific rules?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

Pretty simple really. Say I want an analyzer package with a specific rule inlcuded (for example, CA2227). Is there any way to go about finding one? I tried Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, but that didn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

The latest prerelease version `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` (2.0.0-beta2) does include an analyzer for CA2227 that works for me.

Though if you install that package, you will also get many warnings similar to:

> Analyzer 'SomeAnalyzerName' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' with message 'Feature 'IOperation' is disabled.'.

The reason for that is that some of the analyzers use the unfinished `IOperation` feature. If you're sure you want to enable it, add `<Features>IOperation</Features>` to your csproj.

Comment: This gives the answer for the example rule, but is there a way to find this out for any arbitrary rule? I'm finding that nuget packages do an awful job of advertising what rules they contain, and specific rules may be included in multiple packages.